# Loop within a function to alt color table rows

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a query building form built in PHP.  The results of the query are returned and placed in two different tables one above the other. (table id's are results, and results2)  Each record returned builds two tables to display its data. (Soon to be three)

I'm using the following code to change the class tags of my `<tr>`'s to provide alternate row coloring:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function alternate(id){
  if(document.getElementsByTagName){
    var table = document.getElementById(id);
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
      if(i % 2 == 0){
       rows[i].className = "row-one";
       }else{
       rows[i].className = "row-two";
            }
          }
         }
        }
</script>
```

Then I'm using a body onload like so:

```
<body onload="alternate('results'); alternate('results2');">
```

The problem is it only colors the first two instances of these tables, when depending on the amount of records returned there could be hundreds of them.

How can I get this function to apply to every table in the document with a id = results and results2 and soon to be a results3?

Comment: Why not do this in PHP when the page is built, not after the document has already been delivered to the browser? Also, be aware that in HTML element IDs should be unique -- this is why it's only applying to the first instances of each ID.

Comment: When you say "it only colors the first two instances of these tables" do you mean only the first two rows of each table are colored?  Or only the first two tables have all rows colored?

Comment: Well let me go see if I can find an example of PHP doing this for me. 

Thanks for the suggest Renesis.

Comment: The first two tables with id's results and results2 get colored correctly.

As Renesis pointed out, my first mistake is not using unique HTML id's.

Comment: @Renesis - if you put that as an answer, I'll upvote it as this is most likely the problem here

Comment: So the answer is not to use javascript for this because the id's are not going to be unique?  Surely there's a way to just place a class on every alternate tr on my page.

I do agree though, it should be done in PHP not in dom.

Comment: The answer is *ideally* to assign the CSS classes to alternate rows on the server-side. That way there is no code to execute client-side, the styling will be present for all users including those with JavaScript disabled and you avoid having to send the extra bandwidth for the code to do it. Granted, the server will be doing more work, but the effect on performance in this instance will be negligible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really* want to do this with JavaScript, I would suggest the following code:

First, make your tables have a class of "results" instead of ID "results1", "results2", etc (because as my comment on the question says, IDs must be unique, and getElementById will only return one result and apply to only one real element):

```
<table class="results">...</table>
```

Next, use this JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function alternate(classNameMatch) {
    var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");
    for (var i=0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        var table = tables[i];
        if (table.className.indexOf(classNameMatch) == -1)) continue;

        for (var j=0; j < table.rows.length; j++) { // "TABLE" elements have a "rows" collection built-in
            table.rows[j].className = j % 2 == 0 ? "row-one" : "row-two";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Then call `alternate("results");` on page load.

But, I *really* suggest doing this in PHP.  JavaScript will be *very* inefficient with large result sets.  It will also not show up right away, making the style of the page visibily change after page load.

I would also just add a class to every other row, and then style all rows by default one way and the other class the other way:

```
<style type="text/css">
table.results tr { background-color:#f0f0f0; }
table.results tr.row2 { background-color:#f0f0ff; }
</style>
```

Comment: What if I want to have a column a red, two columns blue, a column red, two colums blue, and so on? Can you help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1):

Of course each call to the method is only applying to one table - you are not looping over a number of tables, but set the `table` var at the top of the document and then colour the rows in *that* table.  As others have pointed out, IDs are meant to be unique within a document anyway, which is why `getElementByID` only returns a single value.

Doing this on the server-side would be *much* better as well, because that's the canonical document sent to everyone so doesn't rely on them having JS enabled, and doesn't take a possibly non-negligible amount of processing time while the page gets striped.

If you *must* do this client-side, a better implementation would be to give your tables a particular *class* (instead of ID); refactor your solution slightly so that you split the core of your functionality into a method that stripes a single table that's passed in; then find all tables with the class "stripeme" (or whatever), and loop over that result, passing each table into your striping method.